# Handle dock state changes

Tags: android, android-intent, broadcastreceiver, intentfilter

My goal is to make an app that reacts to dock state changes. Based on the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/docking-monitoring.html) this should be a fairly easy task, since the [ACTION_DOCK_EVENT](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_DOCK_EVENT) is a sticky broadcast and therfore does not require a BroadcastReceiver.

The problem is that I do not manage to make it "do something" like posting a simple log message or displaying a toast. I have been fiddeling around with the example from the documentation page:

```
IntentFilter ifilter = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_DOCK_EVENT);
Intent dockStatus = context.registerReceiver(null, ifilter);
```

When using this Eclipse tells me the intent dockStaus is unused.I am trying to execute this code from my Application class, since pre Android 3.1, the receiver have to be registered again after every reboot.

Answer (score 1):

The dock-state details are included as an extra in a sticky broadcast of the ACTION_DOCK_EVENT action. Because it's sticky, you don't need to register a BroadcastReceiver. You can simply call registerReceiver() passing in null as the broadcast receiver as shown in the next snippet.

```
        mContext = getApplicationContext();
        IntentFilter ifilter = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_DOCK_EVENT);
        Intent dockStatus = registerReceiver(null, ifilter);
```

You can extract the current docking status from the EXTRA_DOCK_STATE extra:

```
        int dockState = (dockStatus == null ?
            Intent.EXTRA_DOCK_STATE_UNDOCKED :
            dockStatus.getIntExtra(Intent.EXTRA_DOCK_STATE, -1));
        boolean isDocked = dockState != Intent.EXTRA_DOCK_STATE_UNDOCKED;
        boolean isCar = dockState == Intent.EXTRA_DOCK_STATE_CAR;
```

Whenever the device is docked or undocked, the ACTION_DOCK_EVENT action is broadcast. To monitor changes in the device's dock-state, simply register a broadcast receiver in your application manifest as shown in the snippet below: action android:name="android.intent.action.ACTION_DOCK_EVENT"

Hope this helps.